# Load metadata from mysql

Tags: joomla-3.x, images, metadata

I've got articles with single images or gallery created with SIGE on my website, I need to load metadata for each image from mysql database, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, if you mean the meta keywords.
AFAIK, the "Related Articles"-Plugin uses the meta keywords and has a corresponding database-call in its code.
You can find the code for that in:

```
/modules/mod_related_items/helper.php
```

you want to look at lines 53-83 (at least in my version).
The important part (and the answer to your question, should look something like that:

```
// get the database and an array of the existing article_ids
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$article_ids = array() // tbh I don't recall the exact JFactory call you'd
// have to call, but you can probably work that one out.

// all the following is taken from mod_related_articles
foreach ($article_ids as $id) {
    $query->select('metakey')
            ->from('#__content')
            ->where('id = ' . (int) $id);
    $db->setQuery($query);
}

// now trim and explode the result of the query
$metakey = trim($db->loadResult());
$keys = explode(',', $metakey);
$likes = array();

foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    $key = trim($key);
    if ($key) {
        $likes[] = $db->escape($key);
    }
}
```